# Is it possible to get AWS Cognito user password?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Can i be able to get users password from `aws cognito`? Because i have 2 apps and i want to implement single sign on. The way i do it is when i login in the first app then when i click to go to the 2nd app, I will pass the jwt token of the user and validate it in my 2nd app. After validating, I will do the login process. That's the only way i know. I was not able to searched for any other simple way to do single sign on in `aws cognito`. Or is there other way to do single sign on in `aws cognito` in a simple way? I'm still new with this `aws cognito` thing. Please help me with detailed instructions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to get a user password from AWS Cognito. Cognito just lets the user reset his password but it has got no API call to perform password retrieval and it's not meant to do that for security reasons.
The most appropriate way to do that is a token-based authentication (through the JSON Web Token): after a successful authentication, Amazon Cognito returns user pool tokens to your app. You can use the tokens to grant your users access to your own server-side resources, or to the Amazon API Gateway. Or, you can exchange them for temporary AWS credentials to access other AWS services.

If you are using Javascript, there is a powerful SDK for Amazon Cognito Identity (Amplify-js) where you can find several use cases and you will be able to find the use case close to your need [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/tree/master/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js).